# How to fix OptionsMenu with subItem InflateException

Tags: java, android, menu, submenu

I have a Options menu with sub-item menus

My app crashes when I click on the option menu, but I can't decrypt logs

I want to have a option button who open 3 option menu subitems

I have checked few tutorials but I can't see where i'm wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_button_main_activity"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_button"
    android:title="@string/search_button"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/notifications_button"
    android:title="@string/notifications_button"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/help_button"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/help_button"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/about_button"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/about_button"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search_button_main_activity:
            this.launchSearchActivity();
            return true;
        case R.id.notifications_button:
            Toast.makeText(this, "This will launch notification feature", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.about_button:
            Toast.makeText(this, "This will launch about feature", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.help_button:
            Toast.makeText(this, "This will launch help feature", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

here's error message :

```
2019-07-01 16:12:46.581 com.matt.android.mynews E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.matt.android.mynews, PID: 7624
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: Binary XML file line #51: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:461)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:771)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:704)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:87)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:83)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:177)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:102)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:94)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:161)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:174)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:208)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:806)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Logs can't tell me where the crash come from

Comment: On line 51 of your XML you should have a TextView. that TextView seems to contain an attribute that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is not from the menu. It's most probably from the layout you're calling in `launchSearchActivity`.

As I understand what you want is something like below

[image]

You can have a menu like that with the xml given below(Please change the drawables, names and ids as you want)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_rate" android:title="@string/action_rate"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp" app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
    android:title="More"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/action_contact_us" android:icon="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/action_about"
            android:orderInCategory="102" app:showAsAction="never"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/action_moreapps" android:icon="@drawable/ic_shop_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/action_more_apps"
            android:orderInCategory="103" app:showAsAction="never"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/action_exit" android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/action_exit"
            android:orderInCategory="107" app:showAsAction="never"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code and replaced ids/drawables by mines but error is still the same XML line 51 and I can't find anything in my layouts [link](https://github.com/matteovaccari/MyNews)

Comment: I've removed inner item tags from "settings" menu to see if app crashs even if they're nothing to show exept a Toast Message and app does'nt crashes

Comment: Looks the problem is in your `fragment_search.xml`, Check this line https://github.com/matteovaccari/MyNews/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_search.xml#L56 . Try to use a hard coded value for `android:hint` and check for the error

Comment: Error is still the same , I've tried to remove textview from this layout but error is still the same, same line 51... Guess it not come from here